# Two GUI applications as different users on the same screen

Tags: x11, su

I am logged as user A. I want to run a GUI application as user B. User, not root. User B is local too, not remote, I only need different environment variables. I don't want to run the second X, I want them on the same display. I have no problem with programs running in terminal, the `su - ...` works. For graphical there is an error message:

```
Application initialization failed: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"
```

or

```
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

Is there a good way to fix it? The article about correct using of `xhost` or something?

Comment: `man xhost` indicates that `xhost +userBname` should work.

Comment: It only returns `xhost:  bad hostname "userBname"`

Comment: @Michas use `xhost +` then, disabling acl

Comment: How about `su - user_b` and then set DISPLAY variable to `:0.0`, for example: `DISPLAY=":0.0" xterm &`?

Comment: @warl0ck Well, it works. I don't think it is good to set this for everyone, though.

Comment: @roomcays The error is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the following command to give `userBname` access to the display:`xhost +SI:localuser:userBname` You may use `xhost +` to give access to everybody; however this is insecure. Better is to give access on a per-user basis. The correct syntax for xhosts entries for local users is `SI:localuser:username`.

Then `su userBname`, `export DISPLAY=:0.0`, and finally run your GUI program. Although you granted access to the display earlier with `xhost`, you must also set the environmental variable `DISPLAY` so that programs know where to place their graphical output. Allowing different `DISPLAY` variables for different users allows multiple users connected to a single machine to use different physical terminals.

Comment: It works. It looks I don't have to set DISPLAY variable.

Answer (score 1):

Just use gksu -u desired username, enter the Password, and you should be ready to go.

```
DISPLAY=:1.0 gksu [-u <user>] [options] <command>
```

Alternatively you could use su  and then set XDISPLAY to the right screen and finally start your desired application.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, the same error.

Comment: What does `echo $DISPLAY` return?

Comment: It returns `:1.0`, the same for main and second user. I had to kill X.

Comment: I updated the command, does it work with DISPLAY prepended?

Comment: It doesn't work. The error is the same.

Comment: What if you `su <User>` on the console and then `export DISPLAY=:1.0` and after that you start the application on this very console? It must be an issue with DISPLAY somehow.

Comment: There is no point id doing `export`, the variable is set already.

Comment: But probably not for the other users environment, hence the error

Comment: It has been set for the other too.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the answer in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I accomplish this:-

1. Open an x-terminal as the user with the existing X session.
2. Issue the command `xauth list`. You should see the X Magic cookie values that authenticate requests to the X-server, for various descriptors. Copy the one with the "unix" reference.
   e.g. 

   `myhost/unix: MIT-MAGIC_COOKIE-1 df8923ae98098fb890c63454c7c`
3. Open a 2nd terminal as the initial user but switch user (su) to the id you want e.g. `su - user2`
4. Now you have switched user, issue the command `xauth add` and paste the line you previously copied at stage 2, then hit return
   e.g.

   `xauth add myhost/unix: MIT-MAGIC_COOKIE-1 df8923ae98098fb890c63454c7c`
5. Start an X program in the 2nd terminal from the commandline e.g.: `firefox`

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

First add your second User to localuser:

```
$ xhost SI:localuser:user2
```

> localuser:player being added to access control list

Than run yor apps:

```
$ sudo -u user2 -H firefox
```