# sudo to another user, but unable to start X applications

Tags: x11, sudo, accounts

This is on Ubuntu 20.04.1, in case it makes any difference.

I open a terminal, sudo to another user, then try to run chromium and get the output pasted below. Every search I've done turns up explanations on how to make this work over ssh, but I'm not using ssh, and trying to use various 'xauth' and 'xhost' commands to get around the issue has proven fruitless.

````
chromium-browser 

(process:534791): dconf-WARNING **: 12:00:39.078: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=61a44bbcabfc450b9dc743459f4eef10 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/1000': Permission denied
No protocol specified
[534746:534746:0111/120039.275234:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1434)] Unable to open X display.```
````

Comment: I can't test this at the moment, but does `sudo -u USER2 chromium-browser` lead to the same error message?

Comment: Yes, same result.

Comment: How exactly are you switching users? If you open up a terminal session with the new user, what does `echo $DISPLAY` and `echo $XAUTHORITY` return?

Comment: Switching user by "sudo -u username -i" but I also tried BulletBob's suggestion with the same result.
echo $DISPLAY
:0
echo $XAUTHORITY
/run/user/1001/gdm/Xauthority
The ID of the user is 1000.
The ID of the user _before_ I sudo is 1001

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74160/315749

Answer (score 1):

So, it looks like (in all my attempts) I never simply did `xhost +` as the original user, which opens up X to allow any other user to put a display on it. I guess that's the problem with having so many suggestions, you can miss out on the obvious one.

For the record, I understand that `xhost +` creates security issues. However, it does demonstrate where and how I need to add permissions, and will allow me to research how to add X permissions more safely.